# Is there a way to turn off rotation of the screen in kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'd like to ask, if there's any way to turn off rotation of the screen in kivy or eventually in another module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are deploying your app to a smartphone, you are able to configure the rotation settings in the buildozer.spec file. This would be the line you are looking for.

```
# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!